Нужен Lua скрипт который выполнит несколько команд из командной строки
Я пытаюсь автоматизировать некоторую методику
Нужно перейти в папку C:\oboi
cd C:\oboi
Выполнить команду
wp id
Получаем id и меняем его в самой крайней команде (мой пример 984242)
wp run mpv --wid=984242 demo2.mp4 --loop=inf --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --force-window=yes --no-audio
Я пока что смог найти команду для запуска команды терминала, но она все равно не хочет работать.
local cmd = "wp run mpv --wid=591036 demo2.mp4 --loop=inf --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --force-window=yes --no-audio"
